# Error when trying to install latest version of mawk

Tags: software-installation, mawk

I currently have mawk 1.3.3 installed on my computer. I tried to install the latest version of mawk (1.3.4) from:

https://invisible-island.net/mawk/#download

I downloaded the source files, extracted the source files from mawk.tar.gz into a folder, then cd'ed into the folder containing the source files. Then I typed the following into my terminal:

```bsh
./configure
make check
sudo make install
```

`./configure` seems to have run fine but `make check` gives me this:

```bsh
** mawk_test
./mawktest: 91: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found

testing input and field splitting
./mawktest: 97: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail wc.awk
./mawktest: 98: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail null-rs.awk
./mawktest: 100: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 101: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 103: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 104: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 106: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 107: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 109: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 110: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 113: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 114: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 116: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 117: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail case 8
./mawktest: 122: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 123: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 125: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 126: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
input and field splitting had 3 failures

testing regular expression matching
./mawktest: 145: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 146: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 147: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 148: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 149: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 150: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 151: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 152: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail reg0-reg7 case
./mawktest: 157: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail noloop2 test
./mawktest: 159: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail noloop1 test
./mawktest: 161: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail case 1
./mawktest: 164: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 165: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 167: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 168: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 170: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 171: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 173: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
./mawktest: 174: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail case 6
regular expression matching had 5 failures

testing checking for write errors
checking for write errors OK

testing arrays and flow of control
./mawktest: 199: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail 
array test had one failure

testing nextfile
./mawktest: 207: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail 
nextfile test had one failure

testing function calls and general stress test
./mawktest: 215: ./mawktest: /home/Documents/Missing: not found
?? fail 
general stress test had one failure
tested /home/Documents/Missing Semester/mawk-1.3.4-20200120/mawk had 11 failures
make: *** [Makefile:107: mawk_test] Error 11
```

Then `sudo make install` gives me the following output:

```bsh
/usr/bin/install -c mawk /usr/local/bin/`echo mawk|    sed 's,x,x,'`
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./man/mawk.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/`echo mawk|    sed 's,x,x,'`.1
```

It doesn't appear to have installed correctly because when I check the version of mawk via
`awk -W version`, I get:

```bsh
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Why isn't it installing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/home/Documents/Missing` doesn't come from the mawk sources.  Perhaps there's a stray environment variable.

The "make check" is supposed to use the build-tree's copy of mawk.  That's the main place to check.  You did not run

```
make
```

which might reflect a missing dependency in the makefile.

Beyond that - by default, configure uses `/usr/local/bin`, and if that's later in your `PATH` than `/usr/bin`, you'll only see `/usr/bin/mawk`.

To configure for /usr/bin, do

```
make distclean
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make check
```

Past that, it's out of scope for StackExchange, perhaps a [bug-report](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues).  More detailed [information](https://invisible-island.net/personal/bug-reports.html) would be needed.

Comment: Ah ok, I actually did try running `make` but it still gave me the same error. Then I moved the source files to my Downloads folder and did `make distclean`
`./configure --prefix=/usr`
`make`
`make check` `sudo make install`. And that worked perfectly. So it had something to do with the path to the source files. Thanks :)